# caching json response using volley

Tags: json, caching, android-volley

I use volley framework to retrieve the json response from the server, but every time  it loads json from the server. How may I cache this json response in order to use it in offline and sync with new response.      The following is my code to retrieve json response from the server

```
          // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest Req = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {    
                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                MainPojo test = new MainPojo();
                                String name = obj.getString("facility_name");                                 
                                test.setName(name);                                
                                //test.setUrl(obj.getString("easyurl"));                                   
                                testList.add(test);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }    
                        }    
                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());                    

                    }
                })
                {            
            //**
             // Passing some request headers
              //*
             @Override
             public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                 HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                 headers.put("Cookie", MainActivity.sharedpreferences.getString(savedCookie, ""));                
                 headers.put("Set-Cookie", MainActivity.sharedpreferences.getString(savedCookie, ""));
                 headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                
                 //headers.put("Content-Type","application/json");
                 headers.put("Accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                
                 return headers;
             } 
         };  
        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(Req);
    }
```

please let me know what I should do to cache json response

Comment: I think my solution is not good because it may prevents volley to get updated when it needs, give it a try and see if it updates itself or not, you can add header to see when volley needs to update

Comment: header is already added, the only problem is to cache the response and sync only when an update is available from server

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but try using shared preferences